# does a function automatically return dynamically allocated variable?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

While Studing the Tree Data Structure, I came across this code which traverse the tree in preorder

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h> 

struct node 
{ 
   int data; 
   struct node* left; 
   struct node* right; 
};

struct node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    node->data = data; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL; 
    return node;
}
void printPreorder(struct node* node) 
{ 
    if (node == NULL) 
        return; 
    printf("%d ", node->data);
    printPreorder(node->left); 
    printPreorder(node->right); 
}    

int main() 
{ 
    struct node *root = newNode(1); 
    root->left   = newNode(2); 
    root->right = newNode(3); 
    root->left->left = newNode(4); 
    root->left->right = newNode(5);  
    printf("\nPreorder traversal of binary tree is \n"); 
    printPreorder(root); 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
  }
```

In the function newNode(int data), even if we remove the return statement the code works totally fine.
So, my question is does the function newNode is automatically returning the node variable or something else is happening?

Any help is Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Aman, What do you mean by `if we remove the return statement the code works` ? If you remove the last line then the code shouldn't compile as it is expecting a return value

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Yes the code run completely fine. As i have come to know recently its because  the compilers (implementing C/C++ standard) are free to do anything as these are undefined by the C and C++ standards whereas language like java does let you compile the code. You might be trying to compile the code in Debug mode that's why it won't let you compile. For more you can read [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is defined to return a value but fails to do so, and the calling function attempts to use the return value, you invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In your case, the program appeared to work properly.  That's one of the ways undefined behavior can manifest itself.  That could change with an unrelated change to your program, such as adding an extra local variable or a call to `printf` for debugging.

If the function says it returns a value, you should ensure it **always** returns a value.

Comment: Most likely, `node` is the last variable the compiler was working with, so it happened to be in the right register for the return value. But you can't rely on this. Tomorrow you might upgrade the compiler and then it might be a different register.

Comment: I find if you omit the `return` and compile with `-O2`, the compiler generates no code at all for `newNode()` and the program crashes. See https://godbolt.org/z/SRKtav

Comment: @Aman Using a gcc with `-O1` or higher also generates no code for `newNode`.  It doesn't crash but it prints an empty list.  These are just a few ways undefined behavior can manifest.

Comment: @Aman: Valid point, I should have been more careful about the language. But I get the same result compiling as C using `-Wall -O2`. https://godbolt.org/z/UuXf9-

Comment: @dbush: I get an exit code 139. Doesn't that mean a seg fault?